# Why DOM element array can be indexOF?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I know `indexOf` cannot be used in an array of objects, e.g. below.

```js
const objs = [
  {name: 'darling', age: 28},
  {name: 'eliot', age: 29}
]
console.log(objs.indexOf({ name: 'eliot', age: 29 })) // print -1
```

However, why DOM element array index can be traced by `indexOf`??
e.g. below

```js
document.getElementById('slides').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#slides > .slide')
  const newNodes = [...nodes]
  console.log(newNodes);
  console.log(newNodes.indexOf(e.target)) // can print out the index
})
```

Comment: For one `{ name: 'eliot', age: 29 }` is a new object and hence not found in your array

Answer (score 3):

Every time the interpreter comes across an object literal when it runs a line - for example:

```
const objs = [
  {name: 'darling', age: 28},
  {name: 'eliot', age: 29} // this line
]
```

or

```
console.log(objs.indexOf(
  { name: 'eliot', age: 29 } // this line
))
```

It creates a **new** object with those properties. They aren't the same.

```js
console.log(
  // two separate objects, which happen to contain the same value
  { foo: 'foo' } === { foo: 'foo' }
);
```

In contrast, when looking up nodes in the DOM, the nodes are generally static - they don't change unless JavaScript runs which explicitly does so. The `e.target` refers to one such static node, and `querySelectorAll` returns a collection of such static nodes.

So they're `===`, and `.indexOf` works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following behavior:

```js
const element = { foo: 1 };
const arr = [{ foo: 1 }, { foo: 2 }, element];

console.log(arr.indexOf({ foo: 1 })); // -1
console.log(arr.indexOf(element));    // 2
console.log(arr.indexOf(arr[0]));     // 0
```

It clearly demonstrates how `indexOf` matches the *reference* to an object, rather than an object with the same keys and values.

Comment: thank, you. Point is, when it comes to data structure other than primitive type, we take it's reference right?

Comment: Not necessarily. In your case, when you fetch document elements you get them by reference

Answer (score 1):

For one `{ name: 'eliot', age: 29 }` is a new object and hence not found in your array

So you can find an object if it is the actual same object

Otherwise look for it by the value of one or more of the entries

```js
const objs = [
  {name: 'darling', age: 28},
  {name: 'eliot', age: 29}
]

const objToFind = objs[1]
    
console.log(objs.indexOf(objToFind))

// find the index by name

const idxOfEliot = objs.findIndex(({name}) => name==="eliot")

console.log(idxOfEliot)
```